# Possible to edit 'Amount Due'?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to change 'Amount Due' on the payment to 'Total Cost'?

I'm trying to use it so people can work out the total cost of different services, so `Total Due` doesn't really fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are embedding your form, there are a few options that will allow you to change some of the pre-defined text on the form.  For more information, please take a look at [this help topic](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/108/faq/how-can-i-override-the-default-form-text).

<sub>Disclaimer: I am an Engineer on the Cognito Forms team</sub>